# How do I create an infinitely scrollable div (y-axis)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to create a column (`<div id="scroller"></div>`) inside of which the user will be able to scroll infinitely upwards or downwards.

I believe the trick is to increase the height of `<div id="scrollee"></div>` downwards every time the user's scroll is about to reach the bottom and increase its height upwards every time the user's scroll is about the reach the top.

Alternatively (seems easier), the top  of `<div id="scrollee"></div>` could be increased every time the user's scroll is about to reach the bottom and vice versa.

However, I can't seem to find the right combination. I tried the 2nd version (increasing the top of `<div id="scrollee"></div>`) and obviously only managed to make it infinitely scrollable downwards. Decreasing the top when moving upwards didn't work so I have omitted that part from the code.

Any suggestions ?

You can see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/1uzdj12d/5/

**CSS**

```
#scroller {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#scroller>div {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
#scrollee {
    position: absolute; 
    top: -10px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 200%; 
    width: 100%;
}
span {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="scroller">
    <div>
        <div id="scrollee"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<span></span>
```

**Javascript**

```
var timeout;
$("#scroller>div").scroll(function ()
{
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $('span').text('scrolling');
    timeout = setTimeout(function ()
    {
       $('span').text('');
    }, 500);
});

$("#scroller>div").scroll(function ()
{
    var currentTop = $("#scroller>div").scrollTop();
    $(this).find('div').css({top : currentTop});
});
```

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1803-creating-a-bidirectional-infinite-scroll-page-with-jquery-and-coldfusion.htm might both worth a read?

Comment: Thanks Ian but this seems too complicated for what I'm trying to achieve, I'm not looking for an infinitely scrollable page but a div. I think moving around the top of `<div id="scrollee>` everytime there's a scroll should do the trick I just haven't found the right combination yet. :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it was easier than I thought :-)

If you want to create an infinitely scrollable div (on the y-axis), all you need to do is set the height of `<div id="scrollee">` to the height of `<div id="scroller">` ***plus 20px***. You also need to set its initial scrollTop to 10px (this will allow an upwards and downwards scrolling).

Now every time a scroll occurs, reset the scrollTop of `<div id="scrollee">` to 10px.

You can see my solution in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/vxzw68jk/22/

If you're wondering why I'm using :

```
<div id="scroller">
  <div>
    <div id="scrollee"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

instead of simply :

```
<div id="scroller">
  <div id="scrollee"></div>
</div>
```

It's because if you set the width of `#scroller>div` to 150% the scrollbar will be hidden which can be useful (at least for my project..), you can check it out here : http://jsfiddle.net/8psu5L6v/1/

**CSS**

```
#scroller {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#scroller>div {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
#scrollee {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 220px; 
    width: 100%;
}
span {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="scroller">
    <div>
        <div id="scrollee"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<span></span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#scroller>div").scrollTop(10);
var timeout;
$("#scroller>div").scroll(function ()
{
    $('span').text('scrolling');
    $("#scroller>div").scrollTop(10);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function ()
    {
        $('span').text('');
    }, 500);

});
```